# Group by prop table for multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, data-manipulation

I have the following dataset and I would like to find out how to group them by Farm and Worker_Type before getting the frequency/prop table for both Tech and profit_2020 column respectively based on the Farm and Worker_Type grouping.

```
Farm = c(rep("Texas",3), rep("Oregon", 5), rep("Iowa",3))
Worker_Type = c(1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1)
Tech = c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1)
Profit_2020 = c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0)
Agric = data.frame(cbind(Farm, Worker_Type, Tech, Profit_2020))
colnames(Agric) = c("Farm", "Worker_Type", "Tech", "Profit_2020")
Agric$Worker_Type = as.integer(Agric$Worker_Type)
Agric$Tech = as.integer(Agric$Tech)
Agric$Profit_2020 = as.integer(Agric$Profit_2020)
```

Thank you!

Ideally, the output will be something like

- the 1/0 column is obtained/extracted from the tech and profit_2020 column

| Farm | Worker Type | 1/0 | Proportion of 1 and 0 for Tech based in farm based on worker type | Proportion of 1 and 0 for Profit based in farm based on worker type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Texas | 1 | 1 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| Texas | 1 | 0 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| Texas | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Texas | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Oregon | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0.5 |
| Oregon | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0.5 |
| Oregon | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0.67 |
| Oregon | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0.33 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, noted on the cbind, thank you! very useful for a beginner like me to skip a few lines of extra codes. I deleted the question as I noted that the way it was phrased was incorrect. I looked back to the suggestion you've given but it did not provide the proportion but just the sum of the column. Nonetheless thanks for your reply, appreciate it :)

Comment: My apologies on deleting, will take note of it. I've updated the question accordingly as well, thanks for pointing out that the 'YES'/'NO' column was missing the explanation, I've replaced it with 1/0 and added in the explanation. xx has been filled up as well. Thank you!